# Real time chart update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, real-time

In my current project I have an algorythm that generats data, this data will be shown in a Linechart, however the chart only updates once the algorythm has ended rather than after each "step".

```
private void simulate(share[] shares)
{
    int k = 0;
    Random r = new Random(); //random values just for testing 
    while (k < 10)//10 steps (10 values for each share)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shares.Length; i++)
        {
            shares[i].value = r.Next(0, 10000);//random a new value
            shares[i].history.Add(shares[i].value);//add the value to the value history
        }
        //now update the chart so that it first shows only one x point than two and so on 
        drawchart(shares);
        k++;
    }
}

private void drawchart(share[] shares)
{
    cHshares.Series.Clear();//clear the chart
    for (int i = 0; i < shares.Length; i++)//for each share
    {
        cHshares.Series.Add(shares[i].name);//add a new share to the chart
        cHshares.Series[shares[i].name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine; 

        int j = 0;
        //draw the lines with each value that exists for each share
        foreach (double value in shares[i].history)
        {
            cHshares.Series[shares[i].name].Points.AddXY(j, value);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I call the drawchart funktion every step why is it that it only shows after all steps are finished?

Comment: maybe Refreshing the Chart will help.

Comment: I have no methode that is called refresh(), Iknow that documentary of such exists but even after adding the requiret Namespaces it still says that chart does not contain a definition for refresh.

Comment: Well c# is case-sensitive, so the method is `cHshares.Refresh();`! You do realize the you are deleteing all Series in the `drawchart` method, right, without any delay..

Comment: oh, thank you. I'm not used to case sensitivity because i don't often work with c#. the drawchart funktion is not only called by simulate so it clears itself before adding the graphs that I want to show. Anyway now it works, many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

you have put your code in a loop like for loop

Comment: Yeah but only the code that adds new values (and entrys for that matter). If i remove the while loop i get a chart that only has 1 x-achis value. The while loop produces 10 x-achsis values and after each x-achsis value it should update the chart, but it does not.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment!

Answer (score 0):

After each drawchart, update your chart. i.e.

```
drawchart(shares);
cHshares.Update();
k++;
```

I hope this will be useful.